# Can't change default web browser in linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, chrome, xdg-open

I recently installed Linux mint 21.1 Xfce 4.16.0. I'd like my default web browser to be google chrome. `dg-settings get default-web-browser` shows `google-chome.desktop` as my default browser. Unfortunately when I open links from the default terminal and when I double click to open web pages from thunar, they both open in Firefox.

I've set google chrome as my default browser from chrome's settings. Why is this happening and what do I need to change?

Comment: Not a Mint problem. It is another `xfce`'s: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638182/xfce4-terminal-change-default-browser